How can I use vue3-tour with script setup?
I'm trying to use vue3-tour, but the documentation only shows how to use it with options API. I found a closed issue where it was shown how to use it with composition API.
This is my code right now:
// main.ts
import { createApp } from "vue";
import router from "./router";
import VueTour from "vue3-tour";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App).use(router).use(VueTour);
app.provide("tours", app.config.globalProperties.$tours);
app.mount("#app");


<script setup lang="ts">
import NavigationDrawer from "@/components/NavigationDrawer.vue";
import { inject, onMounted } from "vue";

const tours: any = inject("tours");

const homeSteps = [
  {
    target: "#owner-btn",
    content: "Click this button to create a owner.",
  },
];

onMounted(() => {
  tours["home-tour"].start();
});
</script>

<template>
  <v-app>
    <NavigationDrawer />
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <router-view />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
    <v-tour name="home-tour" :steps="homeSteps"></v-tour>
  </v-app>
</template>


Unluckly, tours is undefined. What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?
Edit #1
Based on @pqnet answer, this is my code now
// main.ts
import { createApp } from "vue";
import router from "./router";
import VueTour from "vue3-tour";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App).use(router).use(VueTour);
app.mount("#app");

// App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import NavigationDrawer from "@/components/NavigationDrawer.vue";
import { getCurrentInstance, onMounted } from "vue";

const app = getCurrentInstance();

const homeSteps = [
  {
    target: "#owner-btn",
    content: "Click this button to create a owner.",
  },
];

onMounted(() => {
  app?.proxy?.$tours["home-tour"].start();
});
</script>

<template>
  <v-app>
    <NavigationDrawer />
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <router-view />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
    <v-tour name="home-tour" :steps="homeSteps"></v-tour>
  </v-app>
</template>


It still doesn't work, still undefined.
Edit #2
Thanks to @pqnet insights I managed to get rid of undefined. This is the updated code
// main.ts
import { createApp } from "vue";
import router from "./router";
import VueTour from "vue3-tour";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App).use(router).use(VueTour);
app.mount("#app");

<script setup lang="ts">
import NavigationDrawer from "@/components/NavigationDrawer.vue";
import { getCurrentInstance, onMounted, reactive } from "vue";

const app = getCurrentInstance();

const homeSteps = reactive([
  {
    target: "#owner-btn",
    content: "Click this button to create a owner.",
  },
]);

onMounted(() => {
  app?.proxy?.$tours?.homeTour?.start();
});
</script>

<template>
  <v-app>
    <NavigationDrawer />
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <router-view />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
    <v-tour name="homeTour" :steps="homeSteps"></v-tour>
  </v-app>
</template>


But for some reason the tour doesn't start.

when you added the app.provide code, did you stop and restart the app?

@yoduh yes, I did.

according to here:
https://github.com/alexandreDavid/vue3-tour/blob/6f8e44ada5a44f0a18936320c01621b33129782f/src/components/v-tour/VTour.vue#L165
the app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$tours[props.name] property is populated when the component is mounted. For this reason it cannot be extracted at app creation and thus the provide/inject strategy can't work (it will provide undefined).
There is another solution in the issue you refer (https://github.com/alexandreDavid/vue3-tour/issues/5#issuecomment-1003687833) which will work instead:
const app = getCurrentInstance();
onMounted(() => {
    app.proxy.$tours["home-tour"].start();
})

It is not clear to me though if there is a race condition between the two onMounted hooks - in my tests it never happened but this doesn't talk about the order of these hooks
The approach I suggested before (using ref attribute to bind the tour instance) won't work because the start method is not exposed in the instance itself.

tour.value is null.

@PyKKe it should not have that error, maybe you used :ref for binding? It should be without :. It doesn't matter though because that method won't work, see updated answer

I edited my question, it still doesn't work.
